# Can do merge sort but having problem animating the merge sort visualizer in react

Tags: reactjs, cs50, mergesort, visualizer, asynchronous-javascript

My program is currently sorting the array correctly with merge sort. But the problem is the animation part.

In the code, since i am using setArr() with sorted large block of elements of the original array, **the animation is also changing in large block of sorted elements**. Therefore, **the sorting animations are happening so quickly**. Instead, of that, i want the animation **to change one element after one element in sorted order**.

Thank you in advance.

Here is the my current merge sort code:

```
export function mergeSort(arr, setArr, styling, setStyling, speed) {
    async function performMerge(start, middle, end) {
        setArr(preArr => {
            let buffer_arr = [...preArr];
            let buffer_style = [...styling];
            let merged = [];

            let left_buffer = buffer_arr.slice(start, middle + 1);
            let right_buffer = buffer_arr.slice(middle + 1, end + 1);

            while (left_buffer.length > 0 && right_buffer.length > 0) {
                if (left_buffer[0] > right_buffer[0]) merged.push(right_buffer.shift());
                else merged.push(left_buffer.shift());
            }
            merged = merged.concat(left_buffer, right_buffer);
            for (let i = start, j = 0; i < end + 1; i++, j++) {
                buffer_style[i] = "green";
                setStyling([...buffer_style]);
                buffer_arr[i] = merged[j];
            }
            return buffer_arr;
        });

        await new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve();
            }, speed);
        });
    }

    async function performSplit(start, end) {
        if (start < end) {
            const middle = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
    
            await performSplit(start, middle);
            await performSplit(middle + 1, end);

            await performMerge(start, middle, end);   
        }
    }
    performSplit(0, arr.length - 1);
}
```

I have tried correcting the performMerge function by using setArr() inside the for loop. **The animation is work as i expected** but the original array is not updated with partially sorted elements anymore by setArr(). Because of that, **the array are not correctly sorted anymore**.

Here the updated performMerge function that i have tried:

```
async function performMerge(start, middle, end) {
        let buffer_style = [...styling];
        let merged = [];

        let left_buffer = arr.slice(start, middle + 1);
        let right_buffer = arr.slice(middle + 1, end + 1);

        while (left_buffer.length > 0 && right_buffer.length > 0) {
            if (left_buffer[0] > right_buffer[0]) merged.push(right_buffer.shift());
            else merged.push(left_buffer.shift());
        }
        merged = merged.concat(left_buffer, right_buffer);
        for (let i = start, j = 0; i < end + 1; i++, j++) {
            setArr(prev => {
                let buffer_arr = [...prev];
                buffer_style[i] = "green";
                setStyling([...buffer_style]);
                buffer_arr[i] = merged[j];
                return buffer_arr;
            });

            await new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve();
                }, speed);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are calling setArr and setStyling inside a loop. setState is asynchronous operation, this could be the issue of unsortng.